# Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test for equally likely groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, paired-data

I have a data set with results from 50 subjects who each tested two different types of running shoe, A and B, on four different surfaces, (i.e. each subject conducted 8 tests each). After each test they rated the performance of each shoe out of 100. I am interested in finding which shoe has the higher overall rating regardless of surface. I am assuming each surface is equally plausible/likely, i.e. which shoe would I pick if I were about to go for a run but not knowing which surface it was going to be on.

Which statistical test should I use? I am assuming that I should be using a Wilcoxon Signed Rank test but I am unsure whether I should be conducting four of these tests (one for each surface) and aggregating somehow or should I treat it as just two samples (one for shoe A and one for shoe B)?

Comment: > "Which statistical test should I use?" That depends a lot on what question do you want to answer. Do you want to have a good average performance on any of the surfaces? Or would you pick the chance with one shoe that is perfect on a fourth of all surfaces? A boring standard answer would be to compute a multivariate linear regression, but it really depends on what you want. You could compute average performance on the four surfaces for each shoe and then compute a t-test for paired observations or a ranked-sign-test on these averages. Or just take the best shoe w/o statistical testing...

Comment: I would like a statistical solution to find the shoe that has the best average performance on any surface.

Comment: Are there floor and ceiling effects, such as a lot of ratings around 0 or a lot of ratings around 100?